# Prove that $\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3} $ is irrational

Tags: number-theory

I have proven this by cases on $n$.
I would like to see a neater proof. One similar to the proof of the fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: Show $2n^2+2n+3$ is never a square.

Comment: Ok, and how do you do that?

Comment: Which can be shown by a simple congruence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Would you like to have the honour? Please.

Comment: Just look at it mod $3$!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Nah, you first.

Comment: @tc1729 Surely you meant mod 4.

Comment: @DanielFischer Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand we're done. I wasted my energies [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540410/open-cover-for-a-compact-subset/540525#540525).

Comment: No, modulo $3$ works just fine! $2n^2+2n+3\equiv -n(n+1)\pmod{3}$, which can't be a perfect square!

Comment: @tc1729 Why not? That's either $\equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ or $\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm being silly.

Comment: Note though that modular arithmetic only prove that $\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3}$ is not integer. One still needs to show that $\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3}$ rational implies integer, which is very easy, but needed :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Hint:* $2n^2 + 2n + 3 = 2n(n+1) + 3 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume by contradiction that $\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3}$ is rational. Then

$$\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3} =\frac{p}{q}$$

with $gcd(p,q)=1$. Squaring we get $q^2|p^2$ which implies $q=1$. Thus

$$2n^2+2n+3=p^2$$

It follows that $p$ is odd. Let $p=2k+1$

Then

$$2n^2+2n+3=4k^2+4k+1 \Rightarrow n^2+n=2k^2+2k-1$$

**P.S.** Here is the same argument, if you know modular arithmetic:

$$2n^2+2n+3 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$$
thus it cannot be a perfect square.

Hence $n(n+1)$ is odd, which implies that both $n$ and $n+1$ are odd. Contradiction.

Thus $\sqrt{2n^2+2n+3}$ cannot be rational.

Comment: I think you wanted to write:Hence n(n+1) is odd, which implies that both n and n+! are odd. Contradiction and then thus it cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: You write "Contradiction" and you never said what you've assumed, doh! to much time spent in school!

Comment: $gcd(p,q)=1$. Squaring we get $q^2|p^2$ which implies $q=1$ how do you prove this?

Comment: @wild-squirrel Assume by contradiction that $q \neq 1$. Then there exists a prime $k$ which divides $q$. Then $k|q^2|p^2$ hence $k|p^2$. As $k$ is prime you get that $k|p$. Hence $k|p, k|q$ which is a contradiction. You can complete the details at the end ;)